# Image picker presenting behind the UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I've a `UIView` which is added in front of MainWindow. And I wish to present camera picker in that view. But the camera picker always back of the `UIView`.

How to bring the picker to front. I've checked **bringSubviewToFront:** but no effect

Code used for presenting picker

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {
            UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            picker.delegate = self;
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            picker.allowsEditing=TRUE;

            picker.allowsEditing = true;

            [navController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
```

And here is the code used to add my view to window.

```
[self.window addSubview:myView.view];
[myView didMoveToParentViewController:self.window.rootViewController];
[appDelegate.window bringSubviewToFront:myView];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please upload some code

Comment: what is myView? it is navigation control?

Comment: no, its a sidemenu used for selecting sharing options (need in all pages of the app).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it this way?

```
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    picker.delegate = self;
[<yourView> addSubview:picker.view];
```

Comment: No,  This is my code ,     UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            picker.delegate = self;
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            picker.allowsEditing=TRUE;
[navController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: instead of presenting it, try to add it onto a subview. May be this example would give some insight on what I meant: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/57196-uiimagepickercontroller-inside-subview-in-popover.html

Comment: if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.selectedImageView.bounds inView:self.selectedImageView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    self.popOver = popover;
} else {
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}